# Ionic 3 - Google Map JS library Markers opacity set to 0.1 automatically

Tags: javascript, maps, ionic3

I have integrated the Google maps JS library. I created custom markers and trying to display them on the map but they didnt show up. I checked and found that their opacities are set to 0.1. If I change it via CSS, it works but I don't want to do that as its a workaround. Also I tried settings their opacities manually via marker options but that didn't work as well. Below is my code. Please assist.

```
createMarker(position, icon, title) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: this.map,
  icon: icon,
  opacity: 1,
  title: title
})


this.createMarker(leg.start_location, this.icons.start, 'A');
```

Below is the CSS automatically applied after rendering:

```
div.gmnoprint {
    width: 60px;
    height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.01;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: -29px;
    top: -40px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a [setOpacity()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) method for markers. Make sure no other script is using it... (be careful there is also a setOpacity method for the ground overlay and the tiles)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it already but still doesn't seem to work.